# How to add React App to a Firebase Hosting project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have created a simple *CRUD RESTful API* using **Firebase Functions/Hosting**.

Now I would like to build the corresponding **frontend using React** to query my API.

However, I have no idea *how to cleanly add a new React app to my project folder* and deploy it to Firebase Hosting.

This is my folder structure at the moment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVEql.jpg

The whole API lives in "`index.ts`" in the functions folder. (I know, not good to have it all in one file).

**Where/how do I add a React App and deploy it to Hosting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API using Cloud Functions is a separate project and your front-end App is a separate project. You may keep the two projects separate or together in the same folder is your personal choice.

Having said that, `firebase-tools` installs the project for cloud functions in the `functions` folder, so that your main front-end project can reside as the parent folder. Firebase has few files in the parent folder to store the firebase settings which generally do not interfere with your front-end app.

For deployment, you can deploy API and front-end app in same hosting or different, choice again is yours. In case, you deploy on the same firebase hosting, you can set up rules in `firebase.json` to differentiate the routes for your functions and app.